# IF evaluation in Field codes checking for last page in Word 2011

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, field-codes, conditional-statements

I am trying to use the IF field code in Word but I am getting radically unpredictable behavior.

My syntax is this:

```
{IF PAGE = NUMPAGES "YES" "NO"}
```

I have inserted it into a footer, text box, inline with the document and anything else I can think of to troubleshoot. My outcomes have been getting either a "1" the last page number, nothing or syntax errors with no real pattern as to why. What am I doing wrong? This is not for a mail merge, this is for a word template.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need to nest the { PAGE } and { NUMPAGES } fields like this

{ IF { PAGE } = { NUMPAGES } "YES" "NO" }

where every pair of { } is a pair of the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

If you are using chapter-page numbering that doesn't work, but

{ IF { PAGE #0 } = { NUMPAGES } "YES" "NO" }

works in at least some cases.

Comment: (On Mac Word you wold typically use cmd-F9 or fn-cmd-F9 to get those {} pairs)